# Can Azure API Management be used in reverse?, i.e. to wrap 3rd party API's

Tags: azure-api-management

Can Azure API Management be used in reverse?, i.e. to wrap 3rd party API's

We are having to use some external 3rd party API's and there are various issues, which API Management policies would solve.

Is it valid to have our internal calls route through API Management to the external site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no problems with this setup, ultimately APIM does not require you to own backend services you're invoking.